# Re-arranging lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, let's say `listOne = ['a','b','c']` and `listTwo = [['d'], ['e'], ['f']]` and I also have a function `MyFunction` which takes `listOne` as a parameter and re-arranges it according to a bunch of conditions, then returns it.

So now I have `listOne = ['b','a','c']`, what I am trying to achieve here is I want `listTwo` also be arranged exactly how `listOne` got re-arranged.

So my listTwo would end up as `listTwo = [['e'], ['d'], ['f']]`

I know this can be achieved through `loop` or `if` statements but is there any built-in function or maybe a very efficient piece of code that can achieve this in a short amount of time without using a number of steps?

Comment: Are the values in listOne unique or can there be duplicates ?

Comment: Cant you just parse ListTwo through the same function

Comment: @AlainT. they're unique

Comment: You could use python's sorted function on both lists.
sorted(listOne, key=lambda x: x)

Comment: @PotSkill no I can't since there are a lot of conditions, it would take time, since listTwo just needs to be re-arranged the same it's much better to re-arrange it this way

Comment: You are potentially looking for [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), but without knowing the operations that are applied to `listOne`, it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the values are unique, you can build a dictionary of mappings between listOne and listTwo before transforming listOne.  then reorganize listTwo using the dictionary

```
mapping = dict(zip(listOne,listTwo))
listOne = myFunction(listOne)
listTwo = [mapping[n] for n in listOne]
```

*Note that values un listOne must be hashable for this to work*

You can even extend this to more lists with an extra zip:

```
mapping = dict(zip(listOne,zip(listTwo,listThree,listFour)))
listOne = myFunction(listOne)
listTwo,listThree,listFour = map(list,zip(*map(mapping.get,listOne)))
```

If listTwo is not yet available when you apply myFunction to listOne, you can hold indexes in your mapping dictionary instead of values.  Then you can apply the indexes to listTwo (and any other lists) afterward:

```
indexMap  = {n:i for i,n in enumerate(listOne)}
listOne   = myFunction(listOne)
listTwo   = [listTwo[indexMap[n]] for n in listOne]

listThree = [listThree[indexMap[n]] for n in listOne]
listFour  = [listFour[indexMap[n]] for n in listOne]
```

If the list can contain duplicate values, you'll need a little help from the collections module so that the mapping dictionary can contain multiple values of listTwo for each distinct item of listOne (that become keys to the dictionary):

```
from collections import deque,defaultdict

listOne = ['a','b','c','b']
listTwo = [['d'], ['e'], ['f'],['g']]

mapping = defaultdict(deque)
for o,t in zip(listOne,listTwo): mapping[o].append(t)
listOne = ['b','b','c','a']
listTwo = [d.popleft() for d in map(mapping.get,listOne)]

print(listTwo)
[['e'], ['g'], ['f'], ['d']]
```

or using indexes:

```
indexMap = defaultdict(deque)
for i,o in enumerate(listOne): indexMap[o].append(i)
listOne  = ['b','b','c','a']
listTwo  = [listTwo[d.rotate() or d[-1]] for d in map(indexMap.get,listOne)]
```

*This could also be done without the collections module but defaultdict is more convenient (than dict) and deque is more efficient (than list).*

Comment: I like the idea, though I guess this only works if both lists share every item?

Comment: This is an excellent solution, it worked perfectly :D

Comment: @mapf, I believe that is a given. I don't see how the problem definition would work otherwise, let alone the solution.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.